# responsive tabbed layout possible?

Tags: html, css, tabs, responsive-design

Is it possible to do this layout and how would you do it?
The container has a border, just not on top where the tabs are. Here only the selected tab has a top border. The text of the tabs should center, left align would be okay too. But the text of the first tab must not start before the image (there should be the same space on the left).

[image: the desired layout]

Currently the html looks like this but can be changed if needed:

```
<section class="grid-100 grid-parent tabs">
    <header>
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">Tab1</li>
            <li>Tab2</li>
            <li>Tab3</li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <article class="tab visible">content</article>
    <article class="tab">content</article>
    <article class="tab">content</article>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Have you tried any css at all? It'd be nice if you told us what you already tried. This layout is definitely possible, but I kind of feel like I'm doing your homework here if I start working on a solution right niow.

Comment: Yes sorry here is where I stopped as I was unsure if it is possible: http://jsfiddle.net/qmPDG/

Answer (score 0):

This layout is possible, but as mentioned you'll need to post your CSS.

Have a look at [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) which allows you to placed tabbed content within a responsive framework.

You'll need to add a bit of JS to get this running, you can either do this by adding "bootstrap.min.js" or just add the tab script by itself. Here's a direct link to the tab JS documentation http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Your structure can be used for any tabbed interface or an accordion. Please provide your css for your tabs. You can use bootstrap tabs as mention in this post. There some other tabbed solution like foundation tabs and jQuery ui tabs. If your looking for a premium responsive tabbed solution, have a look zozo tabs, which has a lot of examples.

http://zozoui.com/tabs

cheers

FariDesign

Comment: Thanks, I added my code above as a comment. Also I don't want to use JavaScript.